# lodash multidimensional pluck

Tags: javascript, lodash

With the `lodash` library, I'd like to be able to pluck multiple values into a multi-dimensional array, along the lines of:

`var arr = [{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }, { a: 1, b: 4, c: 2 }];`

`_.pluck(arr, ['a', 'c'])` `-->` `[[2, 4], [1, 2]]`

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no pluck on multiple keys, but you can do this:

```
_.map(['a', 'c'], function(path) {
  return _.pluck(arr, path);
});
```

This will return values grouped by key.

### Edit:

```
_.mpluck = function(collection, paths) {
  return _.zip(
    _.map(paths, function(path) {
      return _.pluck(collection, path);
    })
  );
}

var arr = [{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }, { a: 1, b: 4, c: 2 }];

_.mpluck(arr, ['a', 'c']) --> [[2, 4], [1, 2]]
```

this will replace each object by an array of the specified keys.

---

### Without lodash:

```
function mpluck(collection, paths) {
  return collection.map(function(obj) {
    return paths.map(function(path) {
      return obj[path];
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that return `[[2, 1], [4, 2]]` rather than `[[2, 4], [1, 2]]`?

Comment: You are right. Added another solution. But still, the response is that pluck can no do that.

Comment: I like the non-lodash alternative... looks more straightforward in fact

Answer (score 1):

Solution without lodash:

```js
function pluck(arr, k) {
    return arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r.push(k.reduce(function (rr, aa) {
            rr.push(a[aa]);
            return rr;
        }, []));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var arr = [{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }, { a: 1, b: 4, c: 2 }],
    x = pluck(arr, ['a', 'c']);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```