# lodash mapping of keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am just getting my head around lodash, so the answer to this question is probably straightforward.

Say I have the following array:

```js
var arr = [{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }, { a: 1, b: 4, c: 2 }];
```

I'd like to rename some keys (for all objects) and drop another, to give the following new array:

```js
var newArr = [{ x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }];
```

So, that's renaming a, c to x, y, and dropping b.

What's the neatest way to do this with lodash? I think that [mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs#mapKeys) should be employed but that requires an object as input rather than a collection.

This is a similar problem to that posted at [lodash multidimensional pluck](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170557/4070848).

Comment: Do a `_.map()` and in that callback do a `_.mapkeys()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map):

```
_.map(arr, function(obj) { return { x: obj.a, y: obj.c } });
```

Or, as Vohuman notes, you could simply use the native [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function (if [IE8 support](http://caniuse.com/#search=map) isn't a concern):

```
arr.map(function(obj) { return { x: obj.a, y: obj.c } });
```

With ES6 you can be really concise using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), parameter [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and an implicit return:

```
arr.map(({a, c}) => ({ x: a, y: c }));
```

Comment: It should be noted that the native `Array.prototype.map` does the same thing. One doesn't need lodash.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if `_.mapKeys()` will remove unwanted keys from object.
Below I prepared more flexible solution for your task. It can be converted to Lodash function with [_.mixin](https://lodash.com/docs#mixin).

```
var arr = [{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }, { a: 1, b: 4, c: 2 }];

// mapping keys (if not presented - will be removed)
var keysMap = {
    a: 'x',
    c: 'y'
};

var newArr = arr.map(function(a){
    var o = {};
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function(k){
        if(Object.keys(keysMap).indexOf(k) >= 0){
            o[keysMap[k]] = a[k];
        }
    });
    return o;
});

// newArr: [{x: 2, y: 4}, {x: 1, y: 2}]
```

### EDIT:

Lodash solution (should be more readable):

```
var arr = [{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }, { a: 1, b: 4, c: 2 }];

_.mixin({
    mapObject: function(o, keysMap){
        var n = {};
        _.each(keysMap, function(v, k){
            if(!!o[k]){
                n[v] = o[k];
            }
        });
        return n;
    }
});

var keysMap = {
    a: 'x',
    c: 'y'
};

var newArr = _.map(arr, function(a){
    return _.mapObject(a, keysMap);
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but the question is asking for lodash explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map), and [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick):

```
_.map(arr, _.ary(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'a', 'b'), 1));
```

The [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) call makes a callback function that'll create new objects with only the given property names — `'a'` and `'b'` are *partially-applied* to `pick()`.

The [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) function makes sure that only one argument is ever passed to the callback. We need this because `map()` will supply several arguments, and our callback function will only work with the item itself as an argument.